# how to make a text box comma separated while entering the number value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

how to make a text box as comma separated, while entering the number value? I need this comma separation in all possible senarios. Like, keypress, onblur and copy paste.

Comment: requirement unclear please post some code and make it clear

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ?

Comment: when i enter the numbers in the text box, it should convert as comma separated. The same functionality is needed in onblur and when the user copy paste some value in the text box.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this plugin](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask):

```
$("#inputId").inputmask({"mask": "99,99,99"});
```